# Factoring out a parameter

Tags: variable-definitions, variable, factorization

I have some function:

```
f[a_,b_,c_]:=Sqrt[a^2+b^2+c^2]
```

Is there a way that I can factor out parameter (variable) `b` like this:

```
f[a_,b_,c_]:=b Sqrt[(a/b)^2+1+(c/a)^2]
```

in Mathematica, and call these new factored variables `(a/b)` and `(c/b)` as `p` and `q` respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
Simplify[ Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + c^2] /. {a -> p b, c -> q b}, b > 0]
(*b Sqrt[1 + p^2 + q^2]*)
```

?

Comment: It works! Thanks!